# horizontal scroll bar for ListBox element in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT 2.4.0 and my problem occurs when I am populating the ListBox widget. When I put more elements than the ListBox can display the vertical scroller appears just fine and lets the user see all the elements. But when I add a string which is longer than the width of the ListBox, then the horizontal scroller does NOT appear and the user cannot see the end of the string. The code is here:

```
private VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
private ListBox someList = new ListBox();
public void onModuleLoad() {
someList.setVisibleItemCount(5);
    someList.setWidth("180px");
    someList.addItem("Item1");
    someList.addItem("Item2");
    someList.addItem("Item3333333333333333333333333");
    someList.addItem("Item4");
    someList.addItem("Item5555555555555555555555555");
    someList.addItem("Item6");
    someList.addItem("Item7");
    someList.addItem("Item8");
    mainPanel.add(someList);
    RootPanel.get("list").add(mainPanel);
}
```

So, the end of items 3 and 5 get cut off and horizontal scroller does not appear.
I tried adding  *someList.setStyleName("textarea-style1");*  into onModuleLoad() function and defined it in the CSS file like this:

```
.textarea-style1
{
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FBFBEF; 
    FONT-SIZE: 15px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

After doing that I can see both vertical and horizontal scrollers but the horizontal scroller still does not work. It is disabled.

For right now I just set a title for each item from the ListBox so the user can see the popup with the full string by putting the mouse over it, but I would like to use the scroll bar instead.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ListBox` is simply an HTML `<select>`. I don't think there's a way to have an horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thomas, but as I mentioned above, when I set overflow to scroll in the CSS file the problem remains. It makes the horizontal scroll bar appear but unfortunately it is disabled and not functional.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, missed that. TL;DR I guess. Edited answer to remove that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There an [overflow-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) css properties which takes values `visible | hidden | scroll | auto`. This works for me in chrome. Actually I had the reverse problem with the scroll bar not showing as the `overflow` css property was set to hidden by a containing element.